# Ordinal representation of nested strings

Tags: python, ord

I have a table containing:

```
table = [[1,'THEINCREDIBLES'],[2,'IRONMAN']]
```

and I want to convert the words in each list in table into its numeric representation (ASCII).

I've tried:

```
movie = 'THEINCREDIBLES'
h = 0
for c in movie:
    h = h + ord(c)
print(h)
```

and it works but if I were to use a list of lists as table above, I'm getting an error saying `ord expected string of length 1`

```
table = [[1,'THEINCREDIBLES'],[2,'IRONMAN']]
h = 0
for c in table:
    h = h + ord(c)
print(h)
```

edit for @Sphinx

I've done:

```
table = [[1,'THEINCREDIBLES'],[2,'IRONMAN']]
h = 0
ordlist = []
for row in table:
    for c in row[1]:
        h = h + ord(c)
    ordlist.append(row[0])
    oralist.append(h)
    h = 0
print(ordlist)
```

and my output is now:

```
[1,1029,2,532]
```

which is almost close to what I've wanted which is:

```
[[1,1029],[2,532]]
```

how do i enclose each ordinal representation into individual list within a list as above? Do i introduce a new list for this purpose?

Comment: Do you really need your strings to be nested in a list of list?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon yes, the reason so is because instead of just strings in a nested list of list, i would include a number too. In this case, i have [[1, 'THEINCREDIBLES'],[2, 'IRONMAN']]. I left it out cause the focus was just on the ordinal representation of the strings. My apologies

Comment: Sure, I recommend you add that in your question though, because your structure is the reason of your bug and the solution will not be the same

Comment: @OlivierMelançon i have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

for first loop (`for item in table`), item will be one list, not one character as your expected.

So you need to loop again for item[0] to get each character then ord.

Below is the straightforward way:

```
table = [['THEINCREDIBLES'],['IRONMAN']]
result = []
for row in table:
    h = 0
    for c in row[0]:
        h = h + ord(c)
    result.append(h)
print(result)
```

Also you can use map and recude to sum ord of each character in your table.

The codes like below:

```
from functools import reduce
table = [['THEINCREDIBLES'],['IRONMAN']]
print(list(map(lambda item: reduce(lambda pre, cur : pre + ord(cur), item[0], 0), table)))
```

Both above codes Output:

```
[1029, 532]
[Finished in 0.186s]
```

Comment: i would prefer if THEINCREDIBLES and IRONMAN have it's own sum of ordinal representation rather than combining the sum of both movies

Comment: on the way home, will update my answer to meet your requirements later. But it will not be hard, you can do it first.

Comment: because of some confusion for others earlier, I've updated my question with some extras to the table elements above. You may check it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
tables = [['THEINCREDIBLES'],['IRONMAN']]
for table in tables:
    t= ''.join(table)
    h = 0
    for c in t:
        h = h + ord(c)
    print(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bytes` type may do just what you want, it transforms a string into an immutable sequence of ascii values.

```
title = 'THEINCREDIBLES'

sum(bytes(title.encode())) # 1029
```

Now what you need is to apply this only to the nested strings in your `table`.

```
table = [[1, 'THEINCREDIBLES'], [2, 'IRONMAN']]

new_table = [[id, sum(bytes(title.encode()))] for id, title in table]

# new_table: [[1, 1029], [2, 532]]
```

Comment: thanks! It's brilliant but in my level, i have not come across some functions like bytes, encode and etc. It'd be cool if i could deliver the same thing in a more inefficient manner, that is for now, from my edit for user Sphinx above.

Comment: Sure, if you feel it helps you learn to start with more verbose way to solve your problem using a for loop, then I encourage you to do so! But just remember, bytes really just transforms your string into a sequence of integer (ascii values). And it is not a function, it actually is one of Python's builtin types, so it is worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You have lists within your your `table` list. This can be unravelled via a list compression. Below are some examples relating to your data.

```
movie = 'THEINCREDIBLES'

h1 = list(map(ord, movie))

# [84, 72, 69, 73, 78, 67, 82, 69, 68, 73, 66, 76, 69, 83]


table = [['THEINCREDIBLES'],['IRONMAN']]

h2 = [list(map(ord, m[0])) for m in table]

# [[84, 72, 69, 73, 78, 67, 82, 69, 68, 73, 66, 76, 69, 83],
#  [73, 82, 79, 78, 77, 65, 78]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ord() only works on characters. Python represents characters as a string of length one instead of an object in memory with only enough space for a single character. In other words, it doesn't make a distinction between strings and characters.

You've got to convert the strings one character at a time.

[edit] The answer posted the same time as mine suggesting to use ord() in a map function is a good solution. The core concept, though, is that you're passing one character at a time to ord().